# Query reading criteria from a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a query reading criteria from a dropdown form which is working ok.

It is checking for the program version.

i.e. V6,V7,V8 etc.

I would like to add an "ALL" option to the dropdown list so it can display all results. obviously there is no results for version "ALL". is this possible? if so how.

Comment: That is possible, but with no code we are walking in the dark.

Comment: What do you have now as the `RowSource` and `RowSourceType` properties for your dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Use something like;

```
Dim sql As String, strVal As String
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

sql = "SELECT ProgramVersion FROM Table ORDER BY ProgramVersion "
rst.Open sql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

strVal = "All;"
With rst
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        strVal = strVal & Nz(!ProgramVersion, "") & ";"
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

MyCombo.RowSourceType = "Value List"
MyCombo.RowSource = strVal
```